# How to plot a vector field over a contour plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've managed to plot a vector field and a contour plot and would like to display both of them on top of each other, I've looked around but don't quite understand how figure and subplots work. Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Vector Field
Y, X = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:20j]
U =(1 - 2*(X**2))*np.exp(-((X**2)+(Y**2)))
V = -2*X*Y*np.exp(-((X**2)+(Y**2)))
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
UN = U/speed
VN = V/speed
plt.quiver(X, Y, UN, VN, 
           color='Teal', 
           headlength=7)

plt.show()


# Countour Plot
X, Y = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]
Z = X*np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2))
cp = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar(cp)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two issues:

- Calling `plt.show()` in between the plots: this makes them separate figures, instead of overlaying one on the other
- Plotting the quiver plot before the contour plot: so even if you removed the `show()`, the contour plot would cover up the quiver.

Simple fix!

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Contour Plot
X, Y = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]
Z = X*np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2))
cp = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
cb = plt.colorbar(cp)

# Vector Field
Y, X = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:20j]
U =(1 - 2*(X**2))*np.exp(-((X**2)+(Y**2)))
V = -2*X*Y*np.exp(-((X**2)+(Y**2)))
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
UN = U/speed
VN = V/speed
quiv = plt.quiver(X, Y, UN, VN,  # assign to var
           color='Teal', 
           headlength=7)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: contour quiver plot]