# How to plot vector field on image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gradient, calculus

In order to understand visually the involved vector, scalar fields of an image operation which involves calculating, gradient, divergence, laplacian etc, I am trying to plot them also on the image involved. I started with gradient as below, but

1. getting the arrow set rotated (looks like so), compared to image underneath. What am I missing?
2. Also how do I scale them nicely?

MWE:

```
test_img = cv2.imread('images/ring.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
r, c = test_img.shape
gd = 15

test_slice = test_img[::gd,::gd]  # every 15th point

X, Y = np.mgrid[0:r:gd, 0:c:gd]
dY, dX = np.gradient(test_slice)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.quiver(X, Y, dX, dY, color='y')
plt.imshow(test_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Desired style** : (vector field with image underneath instead):

[image]

**Sample Image used:** [link](https://i.postimg.cc/L8m3q6VK/ring-owhite.jpg)

Note: I initially used a png, then then alpha area was giving a nan, so now I have the jpg uploaded.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939821/how-to-plot-a-vector-field-over-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: As I said, those posts are dealing with (x,y) functions, and then overlay quiver on top. I instead wanted to use image. I could not find any SO post where image was used, and its gradient vectors plotted.

Comment: Without having your original dataset, it is difficult to verify — could you upload your ring.png?

Comment: Oh sure. Sorry about that. I just uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: `np.mgrid()` is giving you a transposed (i.e. rotated) matrix, see [this article](http://louistiao.me/posts/numpy-mgrid-vs-meshgrid/) for example.

In the following, I'm using `matplotlib.image` to load the image (which I first converted back into a .png).
I flatten the image (i.e. remove the alpha channel) and use `imshow` with a fitting colormap ("Greys_r"). The important part however is in `Y, X = np.mgrid[0:r:gd, 0:c:gd]`, which you probably would have spotted yourself if your image weren't square to begin with.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

fname="/path/to/ring.png"
im = mpimg.imread(fname)
flat_image=(im[:,:,0]+im[:,:,1]+im[:,:,2])/3.

r, c = np.shape(flat_image)
gd = 4

test_slice = flat_image[::gd,::gd]  # sampling

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
the_image = ax.imshow(
                flat_image,
                zorder=0,alpha=1.0,
                cmap="Greys_r",
                origin="upper",
                interpolation="hermite",
            )
plt.colorbar(the_image)            
Y, X = np.mgrid[0:r:gd, 0:c:gd]
dY, dX = np.gradient(test_slice)
ax.quiver(X, Y, dX, dY, color='r')


plt.show()
```

The resulting image (with the colormap `viridis`, however) seems to do what you want.
[image: Image with quiver]